# Cannot get DOM id of tooltip innerHtml element

Tags: javascript, dom, chart.js, innerhtml

I have a chartjs tooltip where I am creating custom tooltips for specific nodes on a radar chart. As part of the function that is creating each individual tooltip, I am adding content to the tooltip content by the general technique:

```
var innerHtml = "<p>Some html content</p>"; 
innerHtml += "<p>More html content</p>";
```

So, for example, if i wanted to create a canvas and get that canvas id in a separate javascript function:

```
innerHtml +="<canvas id='canvasId'></canvas>";

function createChart(){
        var chart = document.getElementById("canvasId");
        ...
 }
```

This does not work and won't get the id because it hasn't been added to the DOM until the tooltip is created. I have tried some other techniques but haven't had any luck yet. The key is that i haven't found another way yet to add to the inner html without putting it directly in there as a string.